# Which one of these two sentences is unnatural, and why?

Tags: meaning, grammar

A: It gets really hot when I use it for a couple of hours.
Is it supposed to do this? (is it supposed to do like that?)
B: No, it's not supposed to do that, but it can if you use it in direct sunlight.

My question is, is it possible to switch "Is it supposed to do that?" to "Is it supposed to do like that?" and is the latter natural to say? If it isn't, would it be a grammatical problem?

Comment: no, it is not natural at all.

Comment: why?  I don't see any grammatical problem in that sentence.

Comment: you *do* an action, you *are* in a state. You could say "Is it supposed to be like that"? because "like that" is a state something can be in, but it is not an action. "that" is an action, that of becoming hot.

Comment: It is possible for a sentence to be grammatical but not "natural sounding"

Comment: to be specific: if I heard a sentence like that, I would immediately think the speaker is a non-native English speaker, since it is the kind of mistake only non-native speakers make.

Comment: If you're wondering about *this* vs. *that* -- they're usually interchangeable, but *that* can be used to refer to something a bit farther away in the utterance or farther away in terms of physical distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Do* needs an object.

In "Is it supposed to do that?" *that* is the object. In your example, it's actually a demonstrative pronoun for "the act of getting hot."

In "Is it supposed to do like that?" *like that* can't be an object; the *like* is forcing a comparison between something and *that.* The "something" is the act of getting hot; and again *that* is a demonstrative pronoun, this time for "the act of getting hot in the way in which it does".

So you need a noun to be the object of *do.* It could simply be the word *something.*

> Is it supposed to do something like that?

If you want to use an intransitive verb so you don't need an object, you could use *behave* (in your example):

> Is it supposed to behave like that?

All of that said, the most idiomatic sentence is definitely the shortest:

> Is it supposed to do that?